# Making a "Double Border" (border-bottom only) Cross-Browser Compatible

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, border

CSS:

```
.double-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cd888a;
    padding:3px 0;
    height:1.5em;
    position: relative;
}
.double-border:before {
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e0000;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top:0px;
    left:1px;
    right:1px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Demo: https://surgemovement.org/ (See border-bottom on some text)

- Firefox displays it perfect
- IE displays it perfect
- Chrome has an issue: the pseudo:before border is on top and it looks like crap
- (Windows Safari displays it the same as Chrome but I really don't care about that browser)

Any ideas on how to fix this with Chrome?

Note: Because the other "inset" way of doing double borders cannot be border-bottom only, that solution is eliminated.

Comment: There's something else going on with your demo site. I can't recreate the issue in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
.double-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#FFFFFF,direction=180,strength=1);
}
```

Might have to play with the filter a bit (or drop IE8- support :).

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mpjura/tk3x2ad3/

Comment: Hmm. Here it is: https://surgemovement.org/otherbordertest.html

Looks like it has the same issue in Chrome, and only one of the two instances of it are working in IE11. This is a small website and something must be conflicting-- do you have any idea what it might be?